# IndexError: string index out of rang

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print the even index of the letters in a word.

i wrote this code:

```
s = 'strinf'
i = 0
while i <= len(s):
    print(s[i])
    i = i + 2
```

But what happens is the following:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Draft.py", line 4, in 
print(s[i])
IndexError: string index out of range
s
r
n
Process finished with exit code 1**

I get the answer after the error and I don't get the error.
any explanation?
Thanks

Comment: What do you get when you print the values of `i` before using `s[i]` in the loop?

Comment: so what i did changed "print(s[i])" with "print(i)" and it gives "0, 2, 4, 6" @mkrieger1

Comment: Do you think 6 is a valid index for the string `"strinf"`?

Comment: No you are right. it doesn't fit. i got my mistake thanks for your help! @mkrieger1

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `<=` comparison. Change it to `<` and the script will end without error (the length of string ig `6`, but string are indexed from zero):

```
s = 'strinf'
i = 0
while i < len(s):
    print(s[i])
    i = i + 2
```

Prints:

```
s
r
n
```